# On Item Click Listener for RecyclerView - How can I use the position of an item in a recycler view to smoothscroll to another listview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have one recyclerview and one listview. The orientation of the recyclerview is horizontal and it is fixed at the top of the screen following a textview. The listview has another recyclerview inside it. So, when I click on one of the items in the top-fixed recyclerview, I want to move to an identical position of the listview (may be using smoothScrollToPosition).

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    String title = mIntent.getStringExtra("title");
    mRetailer = mIntent.getStringExtra("retailer");
    setTitle(title.toUpperCase());
    headingTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_heading); //heading text
    subHeadingTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_sub_heading); //number of categories text
    }
    mCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    mCategories.clear();
    HorizontalScrollView hr = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_categories);
    hr.setScrollBarSize(10);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.categories_recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setScrollBarSize(10);

    //====== For category Lists ========

    categoryAdapter = new CategoryListViewAdapter(mRetailer);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_detail_listview);
    mListView.setDivider(null);
    mListView.setDividerHeight(0);
    mListView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http://serveraddress/MerchApp/web/get_all_category.php";
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        String cateName, catePName;
        int cateId, cateUid, cateDepth;
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                final String mResponse = response.body().string();
                CategoryActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mResponse);
                            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");  //JSONArray(mResponse);
                            JSONObject ob;
                            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                ob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                cateId=ob.getInt("cate_id");
                                cateName=ob.getString("cate_name");
                                cateUid=ob.getInt("cate_pid");
                                cateDepth=ob.getInt("cate_depth");

                                if(cateDepth == 0) {
                                    mCategories.add(new Categories(cateId, cateName, R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_35dp));
                                    CategoryInfo cateInfo=new CategoryInfo(cateId, cateName, "",CategoryActivity.this);
                                    categoryAdapter.addItem(cateInfo);
                                    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            }

                            // set 2depth(sub) category
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //
                                JSONObject subCateOb =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                cateId=subCateOb.getInt("cate_id");
                                cateName=subCateOb.getString("cate_name");
                                cateUid=subCateOb.getInt("cate_pid");
                                cateDepth=subCateOb.getInt("cate_depth");
                                catePName=subCateOb.getString("cate_pname");

                                if(cateDepth != 0) {
                                    SubcategoryInfo subCateInfo=new SubcategoryInfo(cateId, cateUid, cateName, catePName,"");
                                    categoryAdapter.categoryMap.get(cateUid).getSubCateAdapter().addSubCateItem(subCateInfo);
                                    categoryAdapter.categoryMap.get(cateUid).getSubCateAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            }
                            setHeader(); // set the top header categories

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            LOGGER.info("!# Request error!!!!! : {}", e.getMessage());
                            //return "serverError";
                        }
                    }
                });
                setCategory(); //set the lower categories
            }
        }
    });
}
public void setHeader(){
    mAdapter = new CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter(CategoryActivity.this, mCategories);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoryActivity.this, mCategories.size()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    subHeadingTxt.setText(mAdapter.getItemCount()+" Categories");
}
public void setCategory(){
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryListViewAdapter(mRetailer);
    mListView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.retailers_search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_retailers);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            categoryAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            System.out.println("Submit Executed" + s);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            System.out.println("Changed Executed" + s);
            categoryAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
}
```

**And the Custom RecyclerView adapter Looks like this:**

```
public class CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> 
implements Filterable {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Categories> mCategories;
private ArrayList<Categories> mFilteredCategories;

public CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, 
ArrayList<Categories> mCategory) {
    mCategories = mCategory;
    mFilteredCategories = mCategory;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_header_thumbnail, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
    myViewHolder.mCategoryThumbnail.setImageResource(mCategories.get(position).getCategoryThumbnail());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return mCategories.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView mCategoryThumbnail;
    CardView mCategoryCardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCategoryThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categories_img);
        mCategoryCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categories_card);
    }
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) { charSequence.length());
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // if there is nothing to filter on, return the original List of Retailers;
            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
                results.values = mFilteredCategories;
                results.count = mFilteredCategories.size();
            }else {
                List<Categories> filteredResultsData = new ArrayList<Categories>();
                for(Categories retailer: mFilteredCategories){
                    if(retailer.getCategoryName().toUpperCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase())){
                        filteredResultsData.add(retailer);
                    }
                }
                results.values = filteredResultsData;
                results.count = filteredResultsData.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mCategories = (ArrayList<Categories>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement onItemClickListener in your class.
In this implemented method you are get the position of your recyclerview item.

**example**

```
  Class example implements CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
    Listview listView;//your listview
    ArrayList alListview;//arraylist for your listview
    @Override
    public void onItemclick(int position){
            if(alListview.size()>=position)
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
        }
}
```

**your adapter class**

```
public class CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Categories> mCategories;
    private ArrayList<Categories> mFilteredCategories;
    private PetrolManFilterAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;

    public CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,
                                         ArrayList<Categories> mCategory, PetrolManFilterAdapter.OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        mCategories = mCategory;
        mFilteredCategories = mCategory;
        this.context = context;
        listener = clickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_header_thumbnail, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        myViewHolder.mCategoryThumbnail.setImageResource(mCategories.get(position).getCategoryThumbnail());
     myViewHolder.mCategoryThumbnail.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            listener.onItemclick(position);
        });
    }
    public Categories getItemAtPosition(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCategories.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView mCategoryThumbnail;
        CardView mCategoryCardView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCategoryThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categories_img);
            mCategoryCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categories_card);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) { charSequence.length());
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                // if there is nothing to filter on, return the original List of Retailers;
                if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
                    results.values = mFilteredCategories;
                    results.count = mFilteredCategories.size();
                }else {
                    List<Categories> filteredResultsData = new ArrayList<Categories>();
                    for(Categories retailer: mFilteredCategories){
                        if(retailer.getCategoryName().toUpperCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase())){
                            filteredResultsData.add(retailer);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values = filteredResultsData;
                    results.count = filteredResultsData.size();
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mCategories = (ArrayList<Categories>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemclick(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer but would you mind explaining about how I can use the _**example**_ class in my class?

Comment: example class is your class where you have to implement recyclerview .you just implement CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener in your class and access that interface method .you can implement CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener in your  first class

Answer (score 0):

If anyone out there is facing the same or similar problem, this is how I did it.
First, I created a recyclerview item click listener interface named ***OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener*** as follows

```
import android.view.View;
public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
   void onItemClick(int position, View view);
}
```

With this interface we can implement it in an ***Activity*** or ***Fragment***. This will override the itemclick method in my activity.

Then I added the following into my CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.

```
....
private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
public void setOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onRecyclerViewItemClickListener) {
    this.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener = onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
}
...
```

Up next, in onBindViewHolder method, I declared the layout setOnclicklistener in this manner.

```
...
myViewHolder.mCategoryThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onRecyclerViewItemClickListener != null) {
                onRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClick(position, v);
            }
        }
    });
 ...
```

To get the position of the clicked item of the RecyclerView, I set tag to layout in my CategoryActivity class as follows:

```
...
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
    Categories categories = (Categories) mListView.getTag();
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.categories_img:
            mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
            break;
    }

}
...
```

And Finally, I set my onRecyclerViewItemClickListener to my Adapter in CategoryActivity Class, which is actually found in the setHeader method of my class, as below. (Line 5 is the added code)

```
1 ...
2 public void setHeader(){
3    mAdapter = new CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter(CategoryActivity.this, mCategories);
4    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoryActivity.this, mCategories.size()));
5    mAdapter.setOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener(this);
6    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
7    subHeadingTxt.setText(mAdapter.getItemCount()+" Categories");
8 }
9 ...
```

Updated:-
I forgot to mention this big note.... DON'T FORGET TO IMPLEMENT THE OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener interface.

```
 public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {...}
```